# Find the maximum of R,G,B in a ndarray according to their group stored in a different ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, numpy-ndarray, scikit-image

I'm currently working on image superpixel SLIC segmentation with the package `skimage.segmentation`.

My original image is `3042*4032` (12Mpx). In `skimage`, the array's shape is `(3042,4023,3)`. After the segmentation, I have around 3000 superpixels represented in a `3042*4032` array.

My goal is to **find for each superpixel, the proportion of pixel which have their maximum value on the Red channel, the Blue channel and the Green channel**.

I already have a function which give me the index of the maximum in the entire image :

```
def proportion_majoritaire_rgb_image(img):
    """ In a pixel, which channel [R,G,B] has the maximum value ?

    :param img: image (N,m) skimage rgb
    :return: (N,m) array with indexes [0,1,2]
    """

    return np.argmax(img, axis=2)
```

And by filtering the image on a single label, i can get the proportion of max RGB in a single label :

```
def proportion_majoritaire_rgb_label(img, matrice_label):
    """ 
    :param img: image (N,m) skimage rgb
    :param matrice_label: ndarray (N,m) labels SLIC
    :return: (K, 3) array of K labels and 3 proportions
    """

    indice_max_rgb = proportion_majoritaire_rgb_image(img)

    n_pixel_max_rgb = []

for k in np.unique(image_grains_ble_slic).flat:
    label_data = indice_max_rgb[matrice_label == k]
    n_pixel_max_rgb.append(np.unique(label_data, return_counts=True)[1] / np.shape(label_data)[0])

    return n_pixel_max_rgb
```

The issue is how to get this information for all my 3000 labels without this for loop ? It takes too much time to compute, is there any other way ?

The final output should be a ndarray (K,3) with K labels and for each channel RGB the proportion of pixels which have the maximum value.

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : Using `np.unique(image_grains_ble_slic).flat` as an iterator for the loop seems to be faster, but my goal of avoiding the for loop still stands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hacky because of a [long-standing feature request](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2561) for [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) to allow measuring multichannel images. But, we can hack it together with some repeated calls to [`regionprops_table`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops-table), which gives us vectorised output:

```py
from skimage import measure

index_max_rgb = np.argmax(image, axis=2)
max_index_images = [
    (index_max_rgb == i).astype(float) for i in range(3)
]
proportions_per_channel = [
    measure.regionprops_table(
        image_grains_ble_slic,
        intensity_image=intensity,
        properties=('mean_intensity',),
    )['mean_intensity']
    for intensity in max_index_images
]
proportions = np.stack(proportions, axis=1)
```

By the way, be sure that you use `start_label=1` with SLIC because regionprops ignores the 0 label as belonging to the background.

Comment: Thank you @Juan, your solution executes in less than 2 seconds, compared to 40seconds previously.

If I understand correctly it's using a "simplified' intensity image that makes such a difference ?

Comment: EDIT : However I don't understand your `properties` parameter in  `[regionprops_table(img_slic, intensity_image=intensity, properties=('mean_intensity',),)['mean_intensity'] for intensity in max_index_images]`


Why is there an extra `,`, and why are you calculating `mean_intensity` twice ?

Comment: `properties=` is the keyword argument that tells the function which properties to compute for each region. It needs to be a sequence (tuple or list) of properties. (x,) is a tuple with one value, while (x) is just x. I could have also written `properties=['mean_intensity']`. Then, this returns a dictionary of columns, and we extract the `'mean_intensity'` column — the only one, but we still need to get it! You can find out more with the regionprops_table docs here, and the linked examples: https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops-table

Comment: The speedup is mainly from avoiding `label_data = indice_max_rgb[matrice_label == k]`, which has to do a full pass through the image for every possible label. Even though the passes are fast, you're doing 3000 of them! `regionprops` does it once to find the bounding boxes of all the labels, then a second time for each bounding box to compute the property on a particular object.

Comment: Thanks for all this input, it's very valuable. I'll look into the doc and the source code.